# Minimal installation of C# 8 command-line compiler for "dotnet build"

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-8.0

We need to install the new C# 8 command-line compiler on our Jenkins server.

We found the "Build Tools for Visual Studio 2019" package on the [Visual Studio Downloads page](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/), but when we select the ".NET Core build tools" workload, it wants to install almost 2GB of stuff. This is a problem, as our Jenkins VM has limited disk space.

I've looked through the "Individual components" list, but nowhere do I see anything for "C# 8 command-line compiler". The closest seems to be "Development activities > C# and Visual Basic", but its tooltip says it installs the full IDE and debugger, which we don't need on a build server.

We already have .NET Core 2.0 installed.

What is the minimal set of components we need to install to get the C# 8 compiler installed and working with `dotnet build` and `dotnet test`?

Comment: Isn't .NET Code SDK the subset of Build Tools you are looking for? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: .Net core sdk will be enough. But C# 8 will be aviable in net core 3... You can download [.NET Core 3.0 preview](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.0)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need Visual Studio features during the build - such as building WPF applications, EF .edmx files, test projects using Microsoft Fakes etc, you can use the .NET Core SDK.

You will need to install SDKs with version 2.2.2xx+, 2.1.6xx+ or a 3.0.0.1xx+ preview.

This will allow you to build projects using 8.0 features as long as you set the `LangVersion` property to `preview` or `8.0`

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: I installed the 2.2.202 .NET Core SDK, and that did indeed get it working! Thank you!